# Plotly Zoom tool: drag and drop doesn't do a selection rectangle if selection width or selection height is too small (heatmap)

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

With Plotly.JS, when zoom tool is chosen in the Toolbar, there is a feature that makes that, when doing drag-and-drop to draw a selection rectangle, **if the selected width or selected height is lower than a constant**, the selection box is not a rectangular shape:

[image]

but something else:

[image]

**How to disable this feature?**

```js
const z = Array.from({length: 500}, () => Array.from({length: 100}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)));
Plotly.newPlot('plot', [{type: 'heatmap', z: z}], {});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.16.2.min.js"></script>
<div id="plot"></div>
```

Comment: This is possible for selections instead of zooms by setting `layout.dragmode = 'select'` and `layout.selectdirection = 'd'`. To have the same behaviour for zoom seems to be an open issue: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/3923#issuecomment-497334963